# zf1: trying to add a navigation menu

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm following this video [tutorial](http://www.zendcasts.com/zend_navigation-dynamically-creating-a-menu-a-sitemap-and-breadcrumbs/2009/06/) to add a navigation menu.

So i just added to my `Bootstrap.php` the function that it says at the beginning of the video (`_initNavigation()`), so now it is like this:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initRequest()
    {
        require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Translate');
        $translate = new Zend_Translate('array', APPLICATION_PATH . '/languages', null, array('scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_FILENAME));

        $translate->setLocale('en');
        Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
    }

    protected function _initNavigation()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView();
        $config = new Zend_Config_Xml('/home/tirengarfio/workspace/contractlink/contractlink/wwwAPP/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');

        $navigation = new Zend_Navigation($config);
        $view->navigation($navigation);
    }
}
```

But after that I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception'
>   with message 'Plugin by name 'Language' in
>   /home/tirengarfio/workspace/contractlink/contractlink/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php
>   on line 336

That error is related to a helper I created, but I didn't get that error before adding the `initNavigation()` function in the `Bootstrap.php` file.. So I think the error could be because the new function.. any help?

Comment: Zend_Translate::__construct() only takes 1 argument. You're passing in atleast 4.

Comment: @MikeB, That's not entirely accurate. Zend_Translate() hints to accepting 1 arg `$options = array()`, however the actual code uses `func_get_args` to accept multiple arguments. Passing in the `$options` array would be best but the current code should work.

Comment: if you comment out the new code, does it work again?

Comment: the current error says the plugin has not been registered. Non of the code you have published relates to that function.

Answer (score 0):

It works removing this line:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
```